# Change Button Image Size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, imagebutton

In XCode I have a custom Button with an Image. I want to change the size of this Image Button in Code with `Swift`.
I already tried:

```
ImageButton.frame.size = CGSizeMake(250,250)
```

Answer (score 0):

The property name `size` is a little misleading. You want to change the frame itself using code like this:

```
ImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,250,250)
```

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: Auto layout will override the frames to fulfill constraints.

Comment: I had used 

myButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)